# Prevent Gnome Terminal From Exiting After Execution

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, gnome-terminal

How do you prevent gnome-terminal from exiting after its given command has exited?

I'm calling gnome-terminal from a cronjob, in order to create a terminal accessible to the user. The terminal is initially given a specific program to run. e.g.

```
gnome-terminal --tab -e "/usr/bin/myprog"
```

This works fine, except that when "myprog" exits, so does the gnome-terminal. How do I keep it running, but just drop back to a terminal prompt?

Comment: Another discussion of the same issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512055/avoid-gnome-terminal-close-after-script-execution

Comment: @Ignacio, it's a common term. Google shows over 100k results for it...

Comment: @Ignacio, the terms "shell" and "terminal" are generally synonymous. If your vocabulary or technical environment differs, fine. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Try this:

```
gnome-terminal --tab -- "/bin/bash -c '/usr/bin/myprog; exec /bin/bash -i'"
```

Comment: As of January 2020, the -e option in gnome-terminal still runs properly but throws out the following warning: << Option “-e” is deprecated and might be removed in a later version of gnome-terminal. Use “-- ” to terminate the options and put the command line to execute after it. >> Based on that information, I confirmed that you can run the following command without receiving any warning messages: <<gnome-terminal --tab -- "/bin/bash -c '/usr/bin/myprog; exec /bin/bash -i'">>

Comment: Just what I need.  Only the command today is a little bit changed.  Just to update:

gnome-terminal --tab -- /bin/bash -c '/usr/bin/nasm; exec /bin/bash -i'

Answer (score 21):

[image]

Create a profile (i.e. hold), set "When command exits: Hold the terminal open" and then

```
$ gnome-terminal --tab --profile hold -e /usr/bin/myprog
```

Comment: There should be some way to create a profile with `hold the terminal open` option set via command-line only.

Comment: Depending on your gnome-terminal, you can use gconf or gsettings to set or get tha value of that property: `gconftool-2  -g /apps/gnome-terminal/profiles/Profile0/exit_action`

Comment: For me this keeps the terminal window open, but it doesn't accept any more commands.

Answer (score 4):

Create a shell script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
# myprog-wrapper.sh - runs /usr/bin/myprog and then starts a new bash session
/usr/bin/myprog
/bin/bash
```

Give the shell script execute permission.

Then set up your cron job to call this script instead of directly calling `myprog`:

```
gnome-terminal --tab -e "/path/to/myprog-wrapper.sh"
```

Replace `/bin/bash` with your shell of choice.

Comment: Had to set execution permissions but then this worked well, thanks. Also, `gnome-terminal` wants us to use `--` now instead of `-e`.

Answer (score 3):

You could use xterm or rxvt-unicode instead of gnome-terminal, both of which have the `-hold` option for this purpose.