# How to wait for user input in a terminal called with -e option?

Tags: linux, terminal-emulator

I'm trying to open gnome-terminal (though I think it would be related to any x-terminal-emulator) with a command provided using `-e` option, like `gnome-terminal -e 'ls'`. The terminal is closed as soon as the command is done working, so I need a way to wait for user input to be able to read the result and then finally close the window with Enter press.

I tried `gnome-terminal -e 'ls; read -p "..."'` and it works if I run `ls; read -p "..."` in an already opened terminal, but a terminal called with `-e` option keeps getting closed.

So is there any way to keep the terminal open until some user input is provided while using `-e` option?

Comment: I think this is a duplicate question. [Prevent Gnome Terminal From Exiting After Execution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4465930/prevent-gnome-terminal-from-exiting-after-execution) and possibly this [Avoid gnome-terminal close after script execution?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512055/avoid-gnome-terminal-close-after-script-execution)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Spawn a shell;

```
xterm -e bash -c 'ls; read -p "Press any key ..."'
```