# How to use gnome-terminal to log in a remote linux server(SSH) and executes commands on the server

Tags: gnome-terminal

The code is following:

```
    gnome-terminal -x sh -c "ssh root@ip 'ls'"
```

And the 'ls' can executed well on the server, but after the execution it will log out the server and I want to stay in the server. So I want to know is there any way to solve this problem

Answer (score 2):

Because you are supplying a command (the 'ls' part of your code) ssh will execute it on the remote server then log out of it, just as you experienced.

It you leave out the command, ssh should stay logged into the server,

```
gnome-terminal -x sh -c "ssh root@ip"
```

Comment: Actually I just want to the terminal do not close after the execution and I have tried    gnome-terminal --window-with-profile=NOCLOSEPROFILE     but it reminds me that    profile 'NOCLOSEPROFILE' specified but not found   so I want to know how to solve this problem~

Comment: There's an old post which refers to this problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4465930/prevent-gnome-terminal-from-exiting-after-execution