# autostart terminal and run a single line on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, gnome-terminal, autostart

I want to have the `gnome-terminal` autostart and run a single line like `echo "Hello World"`, after the user is logged in (though the specific point in time is not relevant). Ubuntu automatically logs in the user. What is the best way to achieve this?

I have tried to add gnome-terminal to the list of startprograms, but can't seem to add any additional commands.
`gnome-terminal -- 'echo "Hello World"'` opens an empty terminal, but doesn't run the code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prevent Gnome Terminal From Exiting After Execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4465930/prevent-gnome-terminal-from-exiting-after-execution)

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu you can do it in such a way:

Create a script you want to run, let it be `script.sh`. Make the file executable:

`chmod +x script.sh`.

Open autostart application and add command:

`gnome-terminal --command="/path/to/your/script.sh"`

[image]

Restart.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
gnome-terminal -- bash -c "echo \"Hello World\";bash"
```

But keep in mind that the new spawned terminal will close after the command is done executing. So if you execute without the `bash` as the last command, the terminal will execute, but will be gone before you can see it.