# open a terminal from python

Tags: python, terminal

I'm developing a program that has a button. When pressed, I want to open a terminal that runs:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

I'm using:

```
os.system("gnome-terminal -e 'sudo apt-get update'")
```

This works fine. The only problem is that when the update is finished, the terminal closes.
What can I do to leave the terminal open?

Comment: See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512055/avoid-gnome-terminal-close-after-script-execution

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You could do this:

```
os.system("gnome-terminal -e 'bash -c \"sudo apt-get update; exec bash\"'")
```

Comment: And probably is the same with konsole (if I use KDE)?

Comment: os.system("gnome-terminal -e 'sudo apt-get update'").  Not sure why you need the extra 'bash' when this works just fine.

Comment: @mastash3ff - read the question. "when the update is finished, the terminal closes". The extra bash call makes it stay open.

Comment: is it possible to do this with your termial of choice? For example, I am using alacritty, but making the  substitution "gnome-terminal"="alacritty" does not work.

Comment: that' worked for me. but how to close that terminal?

Answer (score 4):

There are a few choices:

- add `; read -p "Hit ENTER to exit"` to the end of the command line.
- add `; sleep 10` to the end of the command line to wait a bit, then exit.
- Configure gnome terminal:

  Go to the "Edit" menu and click "Current Profile". Click on the "Title and Command" tab. In there, there is a setting called "When command exits". Change it to "hold the terminal open".  You could also create a new profile.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the `-e`:

```
os.system("gnome-terminal 'sudo apt-get update'")
```

Comment: Could not get this to work.  Had to use the -e option as suggested above.

Answer (score -2):

> > import os

> > os.system("Your command") You can also pass custom command as custom variable For example:

> > cmd_to_run = "ls -lat"

> > os.system(cmd_to_run)