# How to avoid gnome-terminal close after opening it from C++?

Tags: c++, gnome-terminal

I am opening a gnome-terminal using the following code as advised [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512055/avoid-gnome-terminal-close-after-script-execution):

```
system("gnome-terminal -e \"bash -c \"echo foo; echo bar; exec bash\"\"");
```

But the terminal does not remain open. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
system("gnome-terminal -e \"bash -c \'echo foo; echo bar; exec bash\'\"");
```

The commands after `bash -c` needs to be in single quotes. At least it worked for me then.