# Linux Mint: Make a script/shortcut that can be clicked and run and will KEEP THE TERMINAL WINDOW OPEN afterwards

Tags: terminal, shortcut, linux-mint

I make a shortcut on the desktop to run some commands in a terminal.
I click it and the terminal window just opens and closes!

Also, I would like to be able to have the script open a second terminal which will run some more commands and also remain open.

Answer (score 1):

Create a script by your favorite method, e.g. right-click on your desktop > Create Document  > name it 'test.sh' > Right click on the document > Properties > Permissions > Allow executing (or use chmod from terminal)

Open it for editing with `gedit`, `KWrite`, `vt` etc.

Here is a script which will run some commands in the parent terminal, run two more commands in a child terminal, and leave both terminals open!

```
#!/bin/bash
echo hello
# open a child window, run two commands in it, and leave the child window open
mate-terminal -e "bash -c \"echo foo; echo bar; exec bash\""  
echo "keep this open"
# leave the parent window open
read
```

Save the file, click and select "Run in Terminal."

An alternate way to keep the terminal windows from closing is:
Open a terminal > Edit menu > Profile Preferences > Title and Command > When Command Exits > Change from "Exit the terminal" to "HOLD THE TERMINAL OPEN"

Line 4 in the script is thanks to
[Avoid gnome-terminal close after script execution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512055/avoid-gnome-terminal-close-after-script-execution)