# gnome-terminal executes commands from file

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gnome, gnome-terminal

I need an example of gnome-terminal command to read lines of text from a file and executes them one by one in different terminal or a tab.

So this would be the process. I would run gnome terminal command and it would read 10 commands from a file. Then it would execute those 10 commands in 10 different tabs/terminals. And of course those tabs/terminals would remain opened. I found this question  [Avoid gnome-terminal close after script execution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512055/avoid-gnome-terminal-close-after-script-execution/3512119#3512119)

The third answer from the top is very helpful. I managed to open 1 command from a file. But I need 1 file with 10 command lines to be opened like I wrote above.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend to use `screen` for this, if that can be acceptable to you.

You could create a `commands.screenrc` file like this:

```
screen bash -c 'command1; echo press any key; read'
screen bash -c 'command2; bash'
screen mutt
screen emacs
screen
```

You can define as many programs as you want. Start `screen` with:

```
screen -c commands.screenrc
```

I don't know what kind of commands you want to run. If you want to see their output, then write like the first example above: execute the command in a bash shell, which will "pause" after the command was executed. Or the second line, which, after running the command will start another bash shell. Otherwise the screen window would exit automatically.

If you are not familiar with `screen`, you will need to learn some basic key strokes to get around, and to be able to switch between windows. The first few pages of [this presentation](https://speakerdeck.com/janosgyerik/time-saving-tricks-on-the-command-line) should be enough to get you started.

Comment: This was very helpful. How can I use this to open 10 commands in 1 rc file and execute them in 10 different terminals. And I need them to remain opened. This is used for video streaming. So in that file I have 10 video stream links and I want to execute them in order for those streams to run.

Comment: Write 10 lines like the first or second line in the example.

Comment: Okey I get that but since I or my partners will edit those commands later I need the actual commands to be in 1 file. So is there a way in bash to say "read line 1 from rc file, open in terminal1. Read line 2 in the file open in terminal2" etc. This is because others will later (maybe) change stream links.

Comment: `screen` runs independently from terminal windows. Inside a `screen` session there will be as many *virtual* windows as commands in the rc file. 10, 15, 100. You can start `screen` from a real terminal window, but since the screen session is independent from the terminal window, you can even close that window, the screen session will continue to run, and you can reattach to it from another terminal window. This might be difficult to wrap your head around at first, it will be more clear if you try it.