# how do I duplicate an instance of bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, fork

I'm writing/debugging a shell, in C, that runs on a while(1) loop, and every time I exit the shell, it closes the terminal, using exit(), that I used to run the executable so I constantly have to open another terminal and cd back to the directory of my workspace in order to continue working. 
I figured this would be a good reason to learn how I could open another terminal process at my current working directory.

PS. I know a better solution, for efficiency's sake, would be learning how to end my executable without closing my terminal, but that's not what I'm asking.

Comment: will this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512055/avoid-gnome-terminal-close-after-script-execution

Comment: How do you start the shell?

Comment: The shell starts when the kernel calls/loads it. Otherwise, your computer wouldn't get past booting and loading the kernel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In bash shell, execute `bash` to open a subshell before running your executable. Id est, run `bash` as the command you run before your executable. Thus, when your executable terminates itself and it's shell, only the subshell will be terminated.

`bash -c name_of_your_executable`

As you mention in your question, the better solution is to end your executable without terminating the shell as well.