# Open multiple terminal tabs, execute commands and continue working on them

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

When I type:

```
gnome-terminal --tab -e 'ls' --tab -e 'ls'
```

Two new tabs opens in a new terminal window with the 'ls' results, but the prompt is not displayed and no more useless. I want to continue working in these tabs normally.

Can you help me? :)

[image: gnome-terminal-tabs]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Avoid gnome-terminal close after script execution?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512055/avoid-gnome-terminal-close-after-script-execution)

Comment: Next time I will search better. Sorry and thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
gnome-terminal --tab -e 'ls; exec bash'
```

Or

```
gnome-terminal --tab -e 'bash -c "ls; exec bash"'
```

Comment: It worked the second option. Thank you very much! :D