# Executing alias commands in newly opened Tabs

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

I have the following bash script in Linux Ubuntu which opens a new terminal with multiple tabs and in each tab it executes `ssh` command to access a remote router:

```
#!/bin/bash

gnome-terminal --tab -e "ssh root@172.16.17.4" --tab -e "ssh root@172.16.17.5"
```

In the bashrc file, I have included the definition of the following alias commands:

```
alias router4='ssh root@172.16.17.4'
alias router5='ssh root@172.16.17.5'
```

When I replace the full `ssh` command in the first script with these alias commands, each Tab gives me the following error:

> There was an error creating the child process for this terminal
>
> Failed to execute child process "router6" (No such file or directory)

How to solve this problem?

**Note:** When I execute the previous alias commands in a maually opened tab, they work perfectly.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could try switching from an alias to a function in your `.bashrc`. According to bash's documentation, functions are better than aliases for most situations. In your situation, since you're not running bash as a login environment, it might work better. Add this to your `.bashrc` and comment out the alias:

```
router4() {
    /usr/bin/ssh root@172.16.17.4
}
```

If that doesn't work on its own, you could try adding `export -f router4` in your `.bashrc` after defining router4.

Answer (score -1):

You need to execute it through `bash`:

```
gnome-terminal --tab -e "bash -c router4"
```

Comment: The terminal launches but the it reports `bash: router4: command not found`. I also added `shopt -s expand_aliases` but nothing changed.

Comment: well, yes, you didn't specify that in your question; to keep the window open check these solutions: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3512861/5348860

Comment: I solved the issue of keeping the terminal open, it is done by changing profile name. Now i have another problem, please check my previous answer.

Comment: is everything in this workflow being done as the same user?