# Multiple tabs and Bash scripting

Tags: bash, ssh, tabs, gnome

I am trying to open multiple tabs and execute a series of commands in each tab. Lets say I open 3 tabs tab1, tab2, tab3. Then in each tab I would like to execute following:

- ssh user@address (PublicKey Authentication is setup and
  hence no need to enter password)
- Launch python scripts (python some.py)
- Hold the tab open after executing the commands to see the outputs.

I went through some threads and have a rough outline for Bash script.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Script running"
gnome-terminal -e "bash -c \"ssh user@address; uname -a; exec bash\""
```

When I run the above script, a new terminal opens and I can see that I have ssh-ed into the target address but the other command `uname -a` didnot execute.

I would like to build upon this to implement the following:

1. Open multiple tabs and run commands. Ex : `gnome-terminal --tab -e
   "bash -c \"ssh user@address; python file1.py; exec bash\"" -tab -e
   "bash -c \"ssh user@address; python file2.py; exec bash\""`
2. Wait for one of the python file to start executing before opening
       another tab and repeating the process for another python file.

Also is there a better way to implement the same task ?

The above code snippet was from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512055/avoid-gnome-terminal-close-after-script-execution).

Comment: I'm not sure you can tweak gnome-terminal from the outside to do this (open tabs).  You might want to have a look at terminal multiplexers like `screen` or `tmux` instead.  With these you can achieve this (and more) quite easily.  They are built for tasks like these.  Gnome-terminal is more for GUI users, not for programming it.

Comment: The next phase is to run these as background processes. Do you think `screen` or `tmux` would be a better option in that case too ?

Comment: `uname -a` doesn't execute remotely because it's executed locally. Syntax is `ssh user@host -c "command"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should consider using `screen` or `tmux` or a similar terminal multiplexer for this.

Example usage:

```
screen -d -m bash -c 'ls; bash'
```

to initiate a screen session in which `ls` was executed and then a shell started, and then

```
screen -X screen bash -c 'date; bash'
```

to create a new *window* in the existing screen session, run `date` therein and then start a shell in that window.

Mind that the programs are run without you seeing their output right away on your controlling terminal.  You can then attach to the screen session using

```
screen -x
```

Which attach you to the running session and will show you one of the screen windows (the virtual terminals of your two running programs).  Typing <kbd>Ctrl-A</kbd> <kbd>n</kbd> will switch through the windows, <kbd>Ctrl-A</kbd> <kbd>d</kbd> will detach you again, leaving the programs running, so you can attach later with `screen -x`.

You can attach from several locations (e. g. from two different Gnome-terminals) to the same running windows.  Both will then show the same contents.

Another advantage of using `screen` is that you can log out and the programs keep running.  If you later login again, you can still attach to the running sessions.

Only a direct attack like a reboot, a kill-signal or an interaction (like pressing <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd> while being attached) will terminate your programs then.

Comment: `screen` indeed looks good. Is there a command to create windows within a session, split the session and load windows into them ?. Now I am using `Ctrl-A`  `c`, `Ctrl-A` `Tab`,`Ctrl-A` `number` to create windows,to toggle split screen and to load windows on the split screen respectively.

Comment: @lets_try To start another window from within screen, you can enter `screen -X screen bash`.  That will create a new window and start `bash` in it.  If you start something else which terminates quickly, e. g. `date`, that will work also but because it is terminating, its window will disappear right after this termination.  So you'd have to be lightningly fast to see the window using [C-a] [n].  To address this issue, have a look at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/47271/prevent-gnu-screen-from-terminating-session-once-executed-script-ends