# signal to bash command

Tags: bash, unix, signals

If I press `CTRL-C` while running this command, I don't see the `hello` message:

```
bash -c 'sleep infinity; echo hello'
```

So I guess the `SIGINT` is sent to `bash`, not to `sleep`? How can I make the `SIGINT` stop the `sleep` instead, so `bash` continue to the `echo`, and `hello` is displayed?

What I'm trying to do in the end is running [this command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4735506/5272165), stop `COMMAND` using `CTRL-C`, and keep `gnome-terminal` open, running `bash`.

Comment: `bash -c 'trap : INT; sleep 50; echo hello'`

Comment: @WilliamPursell awesome :) thanks