# In a script how to get the pid of spawned terminal's shell to execute commands in it using ttyecho?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, terminal, tty

I am using ttyecho (can be installed with `yay -S ttyecho-git`) to execute a command in a separate terminal like so:

```
urxvt &
sudo ttyecho -n /proc/<pid-of-new-urxvt>/fd/0 <command>
```

It does not work because the /proc/pid-of-new-urxvt/fd/0 is a symlink that points to the /dev/pts/x of the parent terminal.
In the spawned urxvt I happen to run zsh. So if I use the pid of that zsh process it works:

```
sudo ttyecho -n /proc/<pid-of-new-zsh-within-new-urxvt>/fd/0 <command>
```

How can I get the pid of the new zsh process spawned within the new urxvt process when I run `urxvt &` ? Or is there a different solution to achieve the same result?

Comment: After `urxvt &`, `$!` contains the PID of the urxvt process. The zsh you are looking for, is a child process of this. Use the `ps` command to get a list of all processes, and pick a line which is a zsh process having the PPID which you have just found.

Comment: Sure. I did that manually and it works. But I want to be able to do this in a script.

Comment: Which part of what do you manually, can't be automatized? You have the pid, you have the output of `ps` .... now just write a program which searches the pid in the whole process list. It's just a text search. You can do it in virtually any language you like; doesn't even have to be bash.

Comment: Agreed but it seems like such a trivial problem I'm hoping there is a cleaner solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pgrep -P <pid-of-new-urxvt>` gives the pid of the child zsh process.
Thx to @user1934428 for the brainstorming

Here is the resulting bash script:

```
urxvt &
term_pid=$!

# sleep here makes us wait until the child shell in the terminal is started
sleep 0.1

# we retrieve the pid of the shell launched in the new terminal
shell_pid=$(pgrep -P $term_pid)

# ttyecho executes the command in the shell of the new terminal and gives back control of the terminal so you can run further commands manually
sudo ttyecho -n /proc/${shell_pid}/fd/0 "$@"
```

So when I launch "script ls" it opens a new terminal, runs ls, and gives back the prompt with the terminal still open.
I just had to add ttyecho in the sudoers file.