# Terminal Tab Disappears when Opened using Bash Script (Gnome on Ubuntu)

Tags: python, bash, ubuntu, gnome, lxc

Using a simple Bash script in Ubuntu 20.04, I am trying to let it create a new Gnome terminal tab, then run an interactive Python script inside a LXC container `my_lxc`.

```
#!/bin/bash
cmd="python interactive_foo.py"
gnome-terminal --tab -- lxc exec my_lxc -- "$cmd"
```

and

```
#!/bin/bash
cmd="python interactive_foo.py"
gnome-terminal --tab -- bash -ic "lxc exec my_lxc -- \"$cmd\""
```

However, when I run either bash script, I notice a new terminal tab opens and closes quickly.

The new terminal tab should remain open and allow me to interactive with `interactive_foo.py`. How can we do this?

---

Also, when on the LXC host, running the following does not do/output anything:

```
lxc exec my_lxc -- "python interactive_foo.py"
```

Comment: Your question seems to be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/3512055/6770384.

Comment: @Socowi I think my `lxc exec` command might be the main problem. Updated the question

Comment: Right, maybe the `lxc` part needs a slightly different solution. But right now I suspect the python script to be the actual problem. If you use `cmd="sleep 100"` does the tab stay open? If so, then your python script may exit prematurely and has to be adapted.